# Page isn't redirecting properly Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

For some reason, I am getting an error when clicking on a protected part of my page:

> Firefox: The page isn't redirecting properly

Here is the method I use in my `ApplicationController`:

```
protected
  def authorize
    unless User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token])
      flash[:notice] = "Please Log in"
      redirect_to :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

For some reason, I am not getting access to `sessions/new`, which is my login page. Any help would be very much appreciated. I checked routes and I have get `sessions/new`.

Comment: what do you have in your logs?

Answer (score 10):

As a well educated guess, I'd say you have this:

```
before_filter :authorize
```

Which will keep redirecting to itself.

You can fix this either by passing only the ones you want:

```
before_filter :authorize, :only => [:action_a, :action_b]
```

Or specify the ones you don't want (probably preferable if you only want to stop your sessions#new action

```
before_filter :authorize, :except => [:new, :create]
```

If your before_filter is specified on an inherited controller (e.g. your SessionsController is inheriting the before_filter from ApplicationController) then you can use skip_before_filter

```
skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:new, :create]
```

Comment: I do get redirected to sessions/new, however the page doesn't load and I get the error. Here is the details of the error: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: @TopChef Yeah, that sounds like a classic case of redirecting to itself.  If my fix doesn't help, please provide your ApplicationController and SessionsController.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the main reason this happens is when we are redirecting to itself. make sure you are not applying the before_action / before_filter to `Session#new`

```
before_filter :authorize, :except => [:new, :create]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `config.force_ssl = true` may lead to redirection from HTTP to HTTPS in your app.