# redirect users to their profile page if they didn't log out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails, and I am not using gems like cancanca or devise.

Suppose I have a user logged in, but he neither has logged out, nor closed the browser. when this user is not logged out, the problem is, he can still see and access the login page. I want to redirect him to somewhere else when he is on this page. I have a function to check the login status.

```
def authenticate_user!
if logged_in?

else
  redirect_to root_path, :notice => ''
end
end


class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

these two things guarantee that if a user is not logged in, he will be directed to the root page. I was trying to put

```
def authenticate_user!
if logged_in?
redirect_to current_user
else
redirect_to root_path, :notice => ''
end
end
```

rails is throwing at me an error complained he didn't know the user. However, I have defined the current_user in the same helper as well.

```
  def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end
```

can somebody help? Thanks a lot

update:
problem solved:
since i have two controllers in my case, so to avoid forever loop with routes, i separated the function. check not logged in and route for user controller, so if not logged in, the page would go to log in controller. check log in in log in controller and route if logged in.

```
def authenticate_user!
if !logged_in?
  redirect_to root_path, :notice => ''
end
end

def authenticate!
if logged_in?
  redirect_to current_user
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `Users` controller and views set up correctly, you should be able to `redirect_to user_path`.

Going forward if you're unsure about a specific path, you can type `rake routes` in the terminal and it will give you a list of all the known routes. Then you just have to append `_route` or `_url` on the end of the 'Prefix'. Pay close attention to the pluralization

Comment: The page isn’t redirecting properly is what rails gives me. My URL specifies that i am on users/16, but somehow i am not authorized to get on it directly.

Comment: Do you have a users show action in your controller?  Do you have your routes set up properly? If you post your code we can look it over

Comment: i am pretty sure my route is correct. resource :users is used by rails to do all the routes.and if i take that very line down, i'll be ok with everything else just users can still access the login page

Comment: in your `routes.rb` it should be `resources :users` not `resource`

Comment: it is resources. i have my rails routes run and all routes are fine. now pinpoint my problem, it is because the action is defined in the same controller. if i change redirect_to current_user to redirect_to login/new, it would work with no problem. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450434/page-isnt-redirecting-properly-ruby-on-rails.   Is there a fix for that?

Comment: one possible fix i think of is to have a different root page for logged in users and not logged in users, but i am not so sure how to implement. my current case would result in a forever loop.