# Rails Pundit ActiveAdmin: page isn’t redirecting properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, activeadmin, policy, pundit

I installed Activeadmin and Pundit gems.

Added 'include Pundit' in application_controller.rb.

Defined package_policy.rb

```
class PackagePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def update?
    user.admin?
  end
end
```

application_policy.rb:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    false
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

And than I get

```
page isn’t redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete
```

in my browser. Maybe, it is infinity loop or something like it.

I had some different configures of package_policy.rb,
but after added application_policy.rb - the result is always error in browser after trying to log in to Activeadmin panel.

Comment: Try reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450434/page-isnt-redirecting-properly-ruby-on-rails):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allowed all actions for all methods in my ApplicationPolicy.

And after I created new policies with needed permissions for my resources.

In ApplicationPolicy:

```
...
  def index?
    true
  end

  def show?
    true
  end

  def create?
    true
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    true
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    true
  end
...
```

In any other policy, for example:

```
...
  def index?
    user.admin?
  end

  def show?
    user.admin?
  end

  def create?
    user.admin?
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    user.admin?
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    user.admin?
  end
...
```